# How to append another HEX value at the end of an existing byte array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have searched on google and checked my findings on https://www.onlinegdb.com/
But so far, I am not satisfied with my trials and errors. Perhaps, I didn't know how to ask.
I am sure that this could be already very known by many people.

Normally I am reading HEX values from UART communication and placing in a buffer array.
But, for making things simpler, I give you that code snippet;

```
uint8_t buffer[20] = {0x7E, 0x00, 0x07, 0xAA, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0xCC};
uint8_t newValue = 0x55;
```

My goal is to *append* `newValue` on `buffer` and that new value has to be seen after the last array value which is `0xCC` in this case.

So, my question is how to do that efficiently?

**Note that:** One of my trials (works OK but not as I wanted);

```
buffer[11] = newValue ;

for(int i=0;i<sizeof(buffer);i++) 
    printf("%02x", buffer[i]);
```

But, then I need to know the position of the last value and increase the position by one which is 11 (0 based counting) in this case.

Comment: You have to know the position of the last value. How would you do that without knowing the position of the last value? Or the count of bytes received from UART? How would you receive any bytes from UART without knowing how many bytes did you receive?

Comment: If you initialize the array `buffer[20]` with 11 values only, you have no way to detect in your code which values are explicitly initialized or not. If you read the values from UART, you should have a variable that tells you how many bytes you have read.

Comment: If you have a HEX value that cannot be received by UART you can use it as "array terminator" (AKA array T-800) but you must always reset the array with that value each time a communication starts from the beginning. If you can receive all 255 values of `uint8_t` you must count incoming values, that is the smartest and fast solution anyway

Comment: Understood, knowing the last position is the only way as I found out and mentioned in my question, got it, thank you all.

Comment: Since `0x00` is apparently valid data, how do you know which byte that is the last one?

Comment: @Lundin, this kind of dilemma always an issue to be solved. I think I am going to opt to use an `ESC` character at the end of the data-block of the message although it has its own difficulties but I don't claim the life is easy. If you have some ideas I'm all ears.

Comment: I have no idea what this data is supposed to be, so I can't tell you how to store it. The normal way to deal with the problem is to store the data size somewhere.

Comment: @Lundin, yes, you are right about to store the length of the data-block of the message somewhere which is an idea and reasonably good one. For your information, this is my data-block from the instance I gave in my question: `0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06`. It has varying length each time. Yesterday, in order to be certain in the message chunks (STX, LEN, CMD, DATA, CHKSUM), I developed a good parser. So, that gives me now opportunity to count lengths for each chunk. Work in progress.